# How do i append json data to the ul elemens ie text and number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How do i append the json data to the html ul elements. am having text and number in the ul element.different numbers corresponding messages should be append.can any one hep me.thankyou.
$(document).ready(function() {

Answer (score 2):

Get the `messages` property( which hold the array ) of returning json object, iterate over array and append li to the `ul`.

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log(data);
  data.messages.forEach(function(v) {
    // select `ul` and append
    $('ul').append(
      $('<li/>', {
        text: v.virtualnumber + ' : ' + v.message
      })
      // or `'<li>'+ v.virtualnumber + ' : ' + v.message + '</li>'`
    );
  });
},
```

Comment: @DineshChandra : you can store if you want

Comment: console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
            $("#errorResponse").html(jqXHR.responseText);
        },

Comment: url is working but with ajax its not working dont lne wher the prob is

Comment: "something bad happend" this one

Comment: @DineshChandra : I think the problem is CORS here

Comment: @DineshChandra : you are calling service in another domain?

Comment: i think dat error will show in console but its not dat mistake i think

Comment: @DineshChandra : are you sure?

Comment: yes am sure its directly gng to else block ajax is call is ot working

Comment: @DineshChandra : CORS occures on ajax call

Comment: @DineshChandra : if data as in image , then you can do it using forEach , same as my answer

Comment: can i do by taking all these elements in div giving an id append data to it dynamically

Comment: @DineshChandra : yup